# Downloading data from the server in real time

Tags: android, image, download, profile

I'm developing an Android app with such a small social network to exchange messages in real time (google gcm) and profiles of registered users. Until now to update the data of the users use an AsyncTask that fetches the data and images from the server and displays it in the profile. Downloading data, however, this will become very slow if there are many images etc.. is there a way to get this information more quickly and place them in the layout xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes if there are images it will slow down the process. You can however download the data through async task only in which you can download the data part. For images there is a concept called lazy loading i.e. download as required. For that you can use the already available libraries provided.

1. [Volley](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley)
2. [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)
3. [Lazy list](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)
4. [Image Loader](https://github.com/novoda/ImageLoader)